# iOS cannot play "slow" or "veryslow" h.264 videos

Tags: ios, video, h.264

I have encoded a video that I want to transfer to my iPad.

Using FFmpeg, the settings are:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 32 output.mp4"
```

When I have tried the presets `veryslow` and `slow`, I get this message when trying to sync the video via iTunes to the device:

> "[Your File] was not copied to the [Device Name] because it cannot be
>   played on this iPad."

However, I have tried encoding the same video using the preset `medium` and sync and playback in iOS's *Videos* app works.

Is there a work-around to get the "slow" preset videos onto the iPad?

Comment: Have you tried [VLC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962)? Also, is there a reason you need anything better than `medium`? From the [FFmpeg FAQ](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#FAQ): "It's diminishing returns: `veryslow` helps about 3% compared to the `slower` preset, `slower` helps about 5% compared to the `slow` preset, and `slow` helps about 5-10% compared to the `medium` preset."

Comment: @AndrewLarsson: Haven't tried VLC, but will do. In my case, `veryslow` saves a few hundred Mb compared to `medium` on a 2 hr long video.

Comment: The App Store page doesn't list much technical information about VLC, but they do have some on their website: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next parameters to ensure compatibility with apple devices.

`-profile:v baseline -level 3.0`

This disables some advanced features but provides for better compatibility. Typically you may not need this setting (and therefore avoid using `-profile:v` and `-level`), but if you do use this setting it may increase the bit rate quite a bit compared to what is needed to achieve the same quality in higher profiles.

Encoding video using H.264 compression:

- H.264 Baseline 3.0: All devices
- H.264 Baseline 3.1: iPhone 3G and later, and iPod touch 2nd generation and later.
- H.264 Main profile 3.1: iPad (all versions), Apple TV 2 and later, and iPhone 4 and later.
- H.264 Main Profile 4.0: Apple TV 3 and later, iPad 2 and later, and iPhone 4S and later
- H.264 High Profile 4.0: Apple TV 3 and later, iPad 2 and later, and iPhone 4S and later.
- H.264 High Profile 4.1: iPad 2 and later and iPhone 4S and later.

A frame rate of 10 fps is recommended for video streams under 200 kbps. For video streams under 300 kbps, a frame rate of 12 to 15 fps is recommended. For all other streams, a frame rate of 29.97 is recommended.

Encode audio as either of the following:

- HE-AAC or AAC-LC, stereo
- MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3), stereo